# SELECT PercentTimeinGC FROM Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory

Tags: iis, wmi, monitoring, wql, prtg

hope you are well.

Goal: extract WMI data FROM Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory PercentTimeinGC, like shown in perfmon = ".NET CLR Memory / % Time in GC"

Enviroment IIS 7, Worker process Garden (4) (ASP .NET4.0 app pools) (4xw3wp.exe processes)

Story: In the local perfmon we can monitor locally the time our 4 instances of w3wp.exe uses on garbage collection, we want to export this data to external monitoring like PRTG or home made watchdog software.

Searching the net and learning about wql scripts and WMI queries lead us to believe this would be simple however this was not the case.

Adding the statement "SELECT PercentTimeinGC FROM Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory" always returns the value "0" no matter what wmi test tool or script we try, however searching for other statements has several time pointed out the this is the correct statement.

So we are missing something or its simply not possible which i dont believe.

Hope anyone here can enlighten us of our short commings ;-)

Thanks, and have a nice day.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

This vbs code will do it.  This was created for splunk to ingest.

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objWMISvc = GetObject( "winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2" )
Set colItems = objWMISvc.ExecQuery( "Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem", , 48 )
For Each objItem in colItems
    strComputerName = objItem.Name
Next

CommandLine = "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe"
processName = "w3wp.exe"

QueryLine = "select * from win32_process where Name = " & """" & processName & """"
Computer = "."
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & Computer & "\root\cimv2")
Set Items = WMIService.ExecQuery(QueryLine, , 48)
For Each SubItems In Items

 If inStr(SubItems.CommandLine, "0") Then
    WScript.Echo "New Event:"
    w3wpRunningCount = w3wpRunningCount + 1
  WScript.Echo "CommandLine=" & SubItems.CommandLine
  creationdate = SubItems.CreationDate
  creationyear = Left(creationdate, 4)
  creationmonth = Mid(creationdate, 5, 2)
  creationday = Mid(creationdate, 7, 2)


  WScript.Echo "CreationDate=" & creationmonth & "-" & creationday & "-" & creationyear
  WScript.Echo "ProcessId=" & SubItems.ProcessId
  WScript.Echo "ThreadCount=" & SubItems.ThreadCount
  WScript.Echo "WorkingSetSizeMbytes=" & SubItems.WorkingSetSize/1024/1024
  WScript.Echo "PeakWorkingSetSizeMbytes=" & SubItems.PeakWorkingSetSize/1024
  WScript.Echo "PageFaults=" & SubItems.PageFaults
  WScript.Echo "EstAddedLatencyInSec=" & SubItems.PageFaults*8/1000
  WScript.Echo "PageFileUsageMbytes=" & SubItems.PageFileUsage/1024
  WScript.Echo "PeakPageFileUsageMbytes=" & SubItems.PeakPageFileUsage/1024

checkProcessorTime(SubItems.ProcessId)
      getclrmemoryobjectproperties(SubItems.ProcessId)
      getclrexceptionsobjects(objectName)
      getclrjitobjects(objectName)
      getclrlocksandthreadsobjects(objectName)
      getclrinteropobjects(objectName)
      getclrloadingobjects(objectName)
      getdpforsqlobjects(SubItems.ProcessId)

Next
WScript.Echo "New Event:"
wscript.Echo "w3wpRunningCount=" & w3wpRunningCount
machineinterrogationstart()


Function checkProcessorTime(PID)
set objService = getobject("winmgmts:")
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//localhost")
Set objItems = objProcess.ExecQuery("Select PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where IDProcess=" &PID& "")
for each objItem in objItems
Wscript.Echo "PercentCPU=" & objItem.PercentProcessorTime
Next
End Function

Function getclrmemoryobjectproperties(PID)
  Set clrmemoryobjects = WMIService.ExecQuery("select * from win32_perfformatteddata_netframework_netclrmemory where ProcessId = " & """" & PID & """")
  For Each clrmemoryobject in clrmemoryobjects
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.Name),"ProcessName"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.AllocatedBytesPersec),"AllocatedBytesPersec"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.FinalizationSurvivors),"FinalizationSurvivors"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.Gen0heapsize),"Gen0heapsize"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.Gen0PromotedBytesPerSec),"Gen0PromotedBytesPerSec"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.Gen1heapsize),"Gen1heapsize"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.Gen1PromotedBytesPerSec),"Gen1PromotedBytesPerSec"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.Gen2heapsize),"Gen2heapsize"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.LargeObjectHeapsize),"LargeObjectHeapsize"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.NumberBytesinallHeaps),"NumberBytesinallHeaps"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.NumberGCHandles),"NumberGCHandles"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.NumberGen0Collections),"NumberGen0Collections"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.NumberGen1Collections),"NumberGen1Collections"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.NumberGen2Collections),"NumberGen2Collections"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.NumberInducedGC),"NumberInducedGC"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.NumberofPinnedObjects),"NumberofPinnedObjects"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.NumberofSinkBlocksinuse),"NumberofSinkBlocksinuse"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.NumberTotalcommittedBytes),"NumberTotalcommittedBytes"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.NumberTotalreservedBytes),"NumberTotalreservedBytes"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.PercentTimeinGC),"PercentTimeinGC"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.PromotedFinalizationMemoryfromGen0),"PromotedFinalizationMemoryfromGen0"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.PromotedMemoryfromGen0),"PromotedMemoryfromGen0"
    echo_out(clrmemoryobject.PromotedMemoryfromGen1),"PromotedMemoryfromGen1"
    objectName=clrmemoryobject.Name
  Next
End Function

Function getclrexceptionsobjects(objectName)
  Set clrexceptionsobjects = WMIService.ExecQuery("select * from win32_perfformatteddata_netframework_netclrexceptions where Name = " & """" & objectName & """")
  For Each clrexceptionsobject in clrexceptionsobjects
    echo_out(clrexceptionsobject.NumberofExcepsThrown),"NumberofExcepsThrown"
  Next
End Function

Function getclrjitobjects(objectName)
  Set clrjitobjects = WMIService.ExecQuery("select * from win32_perfformatteddata_netframework_netclrjit where Name = " & """" & objectName & """")
  For Each clrjitobject in clrjitobjects
    echo_out(clrjitobject.PercentTimeinJit),"PercentTimeinJit"
  Next
End Function

Function getclrlocksandthreadsobjects(objectName)
  Set clrlocksandthreadsobjects = WMIService.ExecQuery("select * from win32_perfformatteddata_netframework_netclrlocksandthreads where Name = " & """" & objectName & """")
  For Each clrlocksandthreadsobject in clrlocksandthreadsobjects
    echo_out(clrlocksandthreadsobject.NumberofcurrentlogicalThreads),"NumberofcurrentlogicalThreads"
    echo_out(clrlocksandthreadsobject.NumberofcurrentphysicalThreads),"NumberofcurrentphysicalThreads"
    echo_out(clrlocksandthreadsobject.CurrentQueueLength),"CurrentQueueLength"
    echo_out(clrlocksandthreadsobject.ContentionRatePersec),"ContentionRatePersec"
  Next
End Function

Function getclrinteropobjects(objectName)
  Set clrinteropobjects = WMIService.ExecQuery("select * from win32_perfformatteddata_netframework_netclrinterop where Name = " & """" & objectName & """")
  For Each clrinteropobject in clrinteropobjects
    echo_out(clrinteropobject.NumberofStubs),"NumberofStubs"
  Next
End Function

Function getclrloadingobjects(objectName)
  Set clrloadingobjects = WMIService.ExecQuery("select * from win32_perfformatteddata_netframework_netclrloading where Name = " & """" & clrmemoryobject.Name & """")
  For Each clrloadingobject in clrloadingobjects
    echo_out(clrloadingobject.CurrentAssemblies),"CurrentAssemblies"
    echo_out(clrloadingobject.RateofAssemblies),"RateofAssemblies"
    echo_out(clrloadingobject.BytesinLoaderHeap),"BytesinLoaderHeap"
  Next
End Function

Function getdpforsqlobjects(PID)
  Set dpforsqlobjects = WMIService.ExecQuery("select * from win32_perfformatteddata_netdataproviderforsqlserver_netdataproviderforsqlserver where Name like " & """%" & PID & "%""")
  For Each dpforsqlobject in dpforsqlobjects
    echo_out(dpforsqlobject.NumberOfActiveConnections),"SQLNumberofActiveConnections"
    echo_out(dpforsqlobject.NumberOfFreeConnections),"SQLNumberOfFreeConnections"
    echo_out(dpforsqlobject.SoftConnectsPerSecond),"SQLSoftConnectsPerSecond"
  Next
End Function

Function machineinterrogationstart()
  getaspobjects()
  getaspappobjects()
End Function

Function getaspobjects()
  Set aspobjects = WMIService.ExecQuery("select * from win32_perfformatteddata_aspnet_aspnet")
  for each aspobject in aspobjects
    echo_out(aspobject.ApplicationRestarts),"ASPApplicationRestarts"
    echo_out(aspobject.RequestExecutionTime),"ASPRequestExecutionTime"
    echo_out(aspobject.RequestWaitTime),"ASPRequestWaitTime"
    echo_out(aspobject.RequestsCurrent),"ASPRequestsCurrent"
    echo_out(aspobject.WorkerProcessRestarts),"ASPWorkerProcessRestarts"
  Next
End Function

Function getaspappobjects()
  Set aspappobjects = WMIService.ExecQuery("select * from win32_perfformatteddata_aspnet_aspnetapplications")
  for each aspappobject in aspappobjects
    echo_out(aspappobject.CacheTotalHitRatio),"ASPAppCacheTotalHitRatio"
    echo_out(aspappobject.CompilationsTotal),"ASPAppCompilationsTotal"
    echo_out(aspappobject.ErrorsDuringExecution),"ASPAppErrorsDuringExecution"
    echo_out(aspappobject.RequestsPerSec),"ASPAppRequestsPerSec"
  Next
End Function

Function echo_out(propertyvalue,propertydescription)
  wscript.echo propertydescription & "=" & propertyvalue
End Function
```